# Run select independent from IF THEN ELSE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this query:

```
DECLARE
   Date_Parameter date;
   Max_Month date;
BEGIN
  Date_Parameter := DATE '2017-04-01';
  select max(month) into Max_month from BALANCE_YEAR2;

  IF Date_Parameter <= Max_month THEN
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select sum(FLARE_MTD_KNM3) FLARE_MTD_KNM3
      from BALANCE_YEAR2
      where month between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR')
        and LAST_DAY(date_parameter);
  ELSE
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select NET_VOL_MTD_KNM3
      from STREAM_D
      where code = 'FLARE' 
      and production_day = LAST_DAY(Date_Parameter);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

which gives the result I need:

```
FLARE_MTD_KNM3
86751.8733412651
```

But I need to add some more queries like the one.  These should run independently from the selects in the IF THEN ELSE clause,  so I don't need it to be inside IF THEN ELSE:

```
   select sum(max(case when code = 'U900' then volume else  null end )) CORR
     from BALANCE_YEAR1
         where production_day between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') and Max_month 
              group by production_day
```

I want to get something like below:

```
FLARE_MTD_KNM3    CORR
86751.8733412651  2387
```

I was thinking something like below but it's not going to work:

```
DECLARE
   Date_Parameter date;
   Max_Month date;
BEGIN
  Date_Parameter := DATE '2017-04-01';
  select max(month) into Max_month from BALANCE_YEAR2;
select 
(
  IF Date_Parameter <= Max_month THEN
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select sum(FLARE_MTD_KNM3) FLARE_MTD_KNM3
      from BALANCE_YEAR2
      where month between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR')
        and LAST_DAY(date_parameter);
  ELSE
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select NET_VOL_MTD_KNM3
      from STREAM_D
      where code = 'FLARE' 
      and production_day = LAST_DAY(Date_Parameter)
  END IF
),
(
   select sum(max(case when code = 'U900' then volume else  null end )) CORR
     from BALANCE_YEAR1
         where production_day between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') and Max_month 
              group by production_day
) from dual;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why do want to try this out which is not allowed in oracle. Please post your expected output as well.

Comment: I know that it's not allowed in oracle, that's why I'm asking. this is just example what I want.

Comment: You cannot open a cursor within a `SELECT` statment. However you can use `CASE` statement to implement `IF-ELSE` struct in your query.

Comment: trying to avoid case statement, I need if then else

Comment: And why do you want to be specific with `IF ELSE`. Do you see any special benefits which is not in `CASE` ?

Comment: I tried with CASE and it doesn't work in my case

Comment: Can you post what have you tried ? If its not working with `CASE` then for sure it will not work with `IF ELSE` as well.

Comment: With IF THEN ELSE I get result I need and it work perfect, the only thing I need to add some more select but run it independent from IF THEN ELSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it will give you the output you require

```
DECLARE
   Date_Parameter date;
   Max_Month date;
   l_corr BALANCE_YEAR.volume%type;
BEGIN
  Date_Parameter := DATE '2017-04-01';
  select max(month) into Max_month from BALANCE_YEAR2;

  select sum(max(case when code = 'U900' then volume else  null end )) CORR
  into l_corr
  from BALANCE_YEAR1
  where production_day between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') and Max_month 
  group by production_day;

  IF Date_Parameter <= Max_month THEN
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select sum(FLARE_MTD_KNM3) FLARE_MTD_KNM3, l_corr as CORR
      from BALANCE_YEAR2
      where month between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR')
        and LAST_DAY(date_parameter)
      group by l_corr ;
  ELSE
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select NET_VOL_MTD_KNM3, l_corr as CORR
      from STREAM_D
      where code = 'FLARE' 
      and production_day = LAST_DAY(Date_Parameter)
      group by l_corr ;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Note that I have retained your logic for the query on BALANCE_YEAR1. Not knowing your data I presume this will return one row. But if you have multiple values for `production_day` then you may need to revisit the GROUP BY clause (or the WHERE condition).

Comment: to APC: brilliant! thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Tony. So you just wanted to budle up you stuff. Then why were you discussing other stuff ??

Comment: one thing, it says "ORA-06550: line 4, column 29:
PLS-00201: identifier 'BALANCE_YEAR.VOLUME' must be declared", how to fix it?

Comment: @Tony - that's an attribute you've introduced since asking your question. Since I don't know your data model or actual code it's pretty hard for me to spot the error. You need to develop the cool eye we need when debugging our own code.